# pass a set of numbers to pgfplotsinvokeforeach <list>

Tags: pgfplots, foreach

Is it possible to pass a numeric set to the list argument of the `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` command? I need something like this:

```
\newcommand{\a}{1,2,...,10}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{\a} {<...>}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to expand the list macro first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mylist}{1,2,...,10}
\expandafter\pgfplotsinvokeforeach\expandafter{\mylist}{%
    #1 \par%
}%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\expandafter\pgfplotsinvokeforeach\expandafter{\mylist}{<...>}` is easier.

Comment: @egreg: Hehe, thanks, you're right. `\expandafter`s make my head hurt.